# How do I integrate date check function in single mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

this is my current function:

```
$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM data1,data2,data3,data4 WHERE person='" .$name. "'");

$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$day = $row['regtime'];
$days = (strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($row['regtime'])) / (60 * 60 * 24);
if($row > 0 && $days < 15){

$row = ['name'];
$row = ['age'];

//etc
```

but above function does double read in `regtime` row. what I am looking is can I club both function into single query?? if yes how??

Comment: Actually my question was how do I include date check function in that mysql_query??

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you only want rows from the last 15 days in the result set?

You don't include how you're joining the data1-4 tables and your `person` field is open to SQL injection, so I'm leaving those parts out, but included below is the way to filter out only records from the last 15 days:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM data1
   WHERE person = :name
     AND regtime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
```

Comment: Actually my question was how do I include date check function in that mysql_query?? and one more how do I prevent sql injection??

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string() or prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @mathew For one, you should use as little as possible functions in query. If I'm right, then mysql `NOW()` function will prevent query from caching, which will reduce performance.

Secondly for preventing SQL injection you could use in mysql - mysql_real_escape_string and do your query like that:
`SELECT * FROM data1, data2, data3, data4 WHERE person='" .mysql_real_escape_string($name). "'`

Also for performance consumption it's better to select columns you are going to need and not mark as **'*'**.

Comment: @Eugene - You are correct about the query cache, but assuming a reasonably sized table and proper indexing, performance should be fine and we're talking about a micro-optimization here.  The vast majority of sites will benefit much more from page-level caching.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you only have one query in this function. If there is nothing missing in your excerpt, there is no double query. If you mean that you use twice $row['regtime'], that is an array read and not a query.